# Using Postgres Fields in Django

Tags: django, postgresql

I've seen
[How to use ArrayField in Django using PostgreSQL DB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25447072/how-to-use-arrayfield-in-django-using-postgresql-db)
but the current error I get happens when I call
    `python manage.py migrate`
I get the error

```
`  Applying game.0001_initial...Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 338, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 330, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 390, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 441, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 221, in handle
    executor.migrate(targets, plan, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 110, in migrate
    self.apply_migration(states[migration], migration, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 147, in apply_migration
    state = migration.apply(state, schema_editor)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/migration.py", line 115, in apply
    operation.database_forwards(self.app_label, schema_editor, old_state, project_state)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/operations/models.py", line 59, in database_forwards
    schema_editor.create_model(model)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 282, in create_model
    self.execute(sql, params or None)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 107, in execute
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 79, in execute
    return super(CursorDebugWrapper, self).execute(sql, params)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 64, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 97, in __exit__
    six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 62, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 316, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: near "[10]": syntax error`
```

After consulting
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/
I still cannot figure out how to use the PostgresSQL fields that are available in Django 1.8 on OS X. This is my first Django app, so instructions would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Database of `settings.py` looks like

```
`DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}`
```

Comment: But you need to show us how did you use the `ArrayField`? We couldn't just guess what you've done wrong without any code.

Comment: Can you show us your `settings.py` section with your database settings? Without the username/password of course. By the looks of `"/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py"` you are using the wrong database backend driver.

Comment: I've seen this but I only got this error after I put in an ArrayField. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33270297/django-db-utils-operationalerror-near-n-syntax-error

I've changed nothing in `settings.py` except 
`INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    ... ... ... 
    'django.contrib.postgres',
    'game',
)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is you haven't setup django to use Postgres, currently it is using the default of `sqlite3`. If you modify your `settings.py` database section to look something similar to this you should not see that error anymore.

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'db_name',                      
        'USER': 'db_user',
        'PASSWORD': 'db_user_password',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '5432',
    }
}
```

Or if you would like a postgres backend that automatically reconnects on disconnection you can use a custom postgres backend called [postgreconnect](https://github.com/mackeyja92/django-postgreconnect). The same instruction works for both, but instead just use `django-postgreconnect` instead of `django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2`.

Comment: I believe the default is 5432. If that doesn't work you can look at the `postgresql.conf` in your `$PGDATA` directory.

Comment: I am getting `django.db.utils.OperationalError: could not connect to server: No such file or directory` using 5432. :/

Comment: Did you fill out the `HOST` section in the settings? Is your postgres server running? Is it listening on `localhost` or even `0.0.0.0`? You can verify this by running `netstat -na  | grep 5432 `

Comment: It is listening in on localhost.5432. I can't figure out what to use for Name and User

Comment: Ok, did you put `localhost` as the `HOST` in your database configuration? Also, you may have to configure postgres if you haven't already. I am not an expert on that so you may have to find a guide to setup postgres correctly. https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-postgresql-with-your-django-application-on-ubuntu-14-04 may help you, the section `Create a Database and Database User` should point you in the right direction.

Comment: Yes, and this looks good! Thank you so much for the pointers!!